# Firing an event from an ASP.NET calendar control's cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, calendar, custom-server-controls

I'm building an Events Calendar using the ASP.NET/C# framework. I'm able to display the summary of events in the respective days cells by data binding manually in the `OnDayRender` event handler. The clients need the ability to click on the events inside the cells to see the details inside a pop up box.

The calendar control provided by ASP.NET does not allow dynamic controls (which can fire events) to be placed inside the cells, so any link button is out of question. After googling, I decided to programmatically add hyperlinks inside each cell which represented the summary and added a javascript function as the hyperlinks `OnClick` event handler. The javascript function accepts the event details and displays them inside an alert box as of now.

I need a lot more functionality inside the pop up box displaying the event details (RSVP, Remind Me etc). Ideally I don't want to go the Javascript route since I don't know it too well. I am more comfortable with C/C++ and C#.

Can someone please give me general pointers on how to proceed with/without javascript ?

How are the event calendars using the ASP.NET framework able to display event firing controls inside the traditional calendar control's cell ? The MSDN library clearly says one can't do that, and I tried and failed, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar is not a particularly nice piece of code, especially when you try to customize it.

I suggest you try some of the calendar/scheduling control suites available. You can start with this one (open-source):

http://www.daypilot.org/daypilot-lite.html